# Why prerequisite for a target is showing empty?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
ifdef CUSTOM_CONFIG
rom: chk_custom_cfg create_custom_binaries
else
rom: create_binaries
endif

chk_custom_cfg:
ifdef CUSTOM_CONFIG
    export CUSTOM_CONFIG 
    $(eval CUST_CFG_DATA_FILES=$(CUSTOM_CONFIG)) 
    export CUST_CFG_DATA_FILES
    $(eval CUST_CFG_DATA_MEM_FILES=$(addprefix bin/,$(notdir $(CUST_CFG_DATA_FILES:.csv=.mem)))) 
    export CUST_CFG_DATA_MEM_FILES 
    $(eval CUST_CFG_DATA_BIN_FILES=$(addprefix bin/,$(notdir $(CUST_CFG_DATA_MEM_FILES:.mem=.bin))))
    export CUST_CFG_DATA_BIN_FILES 
    $(eval CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES=$(subst .bin,_combined.bin,$(CUST_CFG_DATA_BIN_FILES)))
    export CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES 
    @echo existing cfg files $(CUST_CFG_DATA_FILES)
    @echo existing mem files $(CUST_CFG_DATA_MEM_FILES)
    @echo existing bin files $(CUST_CFG_DATA_BIN_FILES)
    @echo existing combined files $(CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES)
endif
build_images: copy_ops_imgs 

create_binaries: config  $(COMBINED_BIN_FILES)

create_custom_binaries: cust_config $(CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES)
    @echo print all the pre required $^
    @echo custom config bin files $(CUST_CFG_DATA_BIN_FILES)
    @echo custom config bin files $(CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES)
```

In the target `create_custom_binaries` when printing `$^` getting only `cust_config` , I expect `$(CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES)` also part of the prerequisite for the target `cust_config`

```
$(CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES) is set when CUSTOM_CONFIG is defined.

e.g:make --debug CUSTOM_CONFIG=.config.csv rom.
```

- Why prerequisite $(CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES) is empty for the target
- create_custom_binaries?  whereas @echo custom config bin files
  $(CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES) gives the correct value!!

I appreciate any pointers on this. My goal is to build different target based on the input saved in CUSTOM_CONFIG

Comment: Why do you set make variables from recipes with `eval`? These constructs are expanded only when make passes the recipe to the shell, not when it parses the Makefile. What about using the [`if` conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions), instead? Something like `CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES := $(if $(CUSTOM_CONFIG),something,something-else)` that assigns a value or another to variable `CUST_COMBINED_BIN_FILES` depending whether variable `CUSTOM_CONFIG` is set or not.

Comment: Thanks Renaud Pacalet, it worked.

Comment: @C_Enthu Please add the answer and close the question if it works.